# ERD relationships rental_car

Tags: sql, erd

So I'm having difficulties with making an erd for a project about renting cars. I think  I'm  almost done, I only have to make the relationship between 3 tables ,2 of them had many to many relationship so I created a third table that I have to connect with the other 2.My problem is I don't know what kind of connection I should use.(I would be really thankful if anyone could also tell me if everything else is right or should I just start over)

[image]

Comment: Which is the 3rd table you created? What are the m:m relationships you are considering? What type of connections do you think are available?

Comment: the 3rd table is order_details and the m:m relationship is between cars and orders. I'm new to sql and this is for a class project and from my understanding i think i have to connect cars and order _details with one: many ,same with orders and order_details